# How do I clearly display small text?

Tags: linux, display, fonts

The font is set to 5px and the characters are ~0.2cm tall as displayed on my monitor.

I have an Acer H236HL 23" 1920x1080 display and my OS is Linux. Graphics card is a Radeon HD 4200.

There's nothing wrong with my vision but this text is blurry from 2' away (I can read it but I'm worried it will damage my vision). It looks all clumped together and the RGB on the edges is out of whack. Screenshot taken in Sublime Text 3.

[image: small text]
So what do I need to do to display the small text?

I've tried antialiasing, hinting, font switches. But that didn't help. Maybe my display isn't ideal for this? In that case, what is the relevant display attribute that I look for in a new display?

Do I truly need higher resolution? My current one is 96dpi.

Comment: Umm, increase the font size?  Rather than fussing about a higher DPI, just get a larger screen if your next objection will be that you can't get enough text on the screen at a larger font size. Inverting the display can also help (back when I got to go from punch cards to a terminal, figuring out the right DIP switches to go from white on black to black on white was a critical thing to make the terminals more usable.) For coding it can sometimes be helpful to rotate the display 90 degrees with modern wide displays (making them tall displays.)

Answer (score 1):

A font of 5px height will always be blurry as 5 pixels are just not enough to display a font smoothly. Subpixel rendering only helps slightly as you can see in the screenshot.

The only way I can think of is if you want to still have the font 0.2cm high, you have to go for a higher DPI monitor which will display more pixels in those 0.2cm.

For example, if you use a monitor with double the current DPI, you can go to a 10px font height and still have the text 0.2cm high. But it will look much sharper.